# Filter specific "collection" from JSON fetch

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, axios

So for example this would be the output but this JSON response will be much longer, I only want to filter out NFT's with a specific contract address (collection) from this response.

Working with axios and typescript in React.

```
{
  "ownedNfts": [
    {
      "contract": {
        "address": "0x3e7b38e7f6c089345ccca785b18890c528636673"
      },
      "id": {
        "tokenId": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ab5",
        "tokenMetadata": {
          "tokenType": "ERC721"
        }
      },
      "balance": "1",
      "title": "The Beginning / 01",
      "description": "Every plan starts with an idea - the conception of something new. This is the beginning.",
      "tokenUri": {
        "gateway": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXuj8hoJgGngkUfBgNUggzCVbZVNFfgyi5WvZuiSuK7aJ/2741",
        "raw": "ipfs://QmXuj8hoJgGngkUfBgNUggzCVbZVNFfgyi5WvZuiSuK7aJ/2741"
      },
      "media": [
        {
          "gateway": "https://nft-cdn.alchemy.com/eth-mainnet/533ed4162c1fb0809092e309790b9b2b",
          "thumbnail": "https://res.cloudinary.com/alchemyapi/image/upload/thumbnailv2/eth-mainnet/533ed4162c1fb0809092e309790b9b2b",
          "raw": "ipfs://QmZMjHkzomQrYPWTTtBSrV3otynxLzybnrrFgo4HJHc5Tm/send-it.MP4",
          "format": "mp4",
          "bytes": 638290
        }
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "name": "The Beginning / 01",
        "description": "Every plan starts with an idea - the conception of something new. This is the beginning.",
        "image": "ipfs://QmZMjHkzomQrYPWTTtBSrV3otynxLzybnrrFgo4HJHc5Tm/send-it.MP4",
        "attributes": []
      },
      }
    },
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I dont know how to filter a JSON response in typescript...

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you have tried, your one challenge with that and an example of desired output.

Comment: Your supplied sample data is malformed and incomplete; consider creating one that can be used to reproduce your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
const filtered = json.ownedNfts.filter(
  nft => nft.contract.address === "the address I'm looking for"
)
```